# BootMetro menu items show too large line space

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to define two menu's in my header using the bootmetro framework. The first is my main menu and the second is my user menu.

For some reason the menu is visualized wrong the second time, the line space of the menu items are too large.

The code used to create a menu looks something like this

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="header-dropdown dropdown-toggle accent-color" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Actions
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem I run in to is shown in the screenshots below. In my second menu the menu item does not take the full with of the menu.

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be in the bootmetro CSS stylesheet and firebug narrows the search a bit (thanks Thanh Trung!). In inspect mode I can clearly see that the a href does not fill the menu item (li) in my second menu, while it does take the max width in my first menu.

The part in the bootmetro CSS looks like this:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Additional question**: What does this '>' cause? I have never seen that before.

In both menus the CSS class "dropdown-menu" is used, BUT, when I remove the body of this CSS class only the first menu changes accordingly.

**Main question**: So why is this class not properly inherited by me second menu item?

For completeness again the HTML code for the second menu (the menu that shows the artifact):

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left">
        <a class="header-dropdown dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <b class="icon-settings"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image: Menu 1]

Correctly visualized menu

[image: Menu 2]

Wrongly visualized menu

[image: Menu 3]

Inspection: the "a" is not taking the full width

[image: Menu 4]

Inspection: the list item is taking the full width

Comment: `>` will select the "direct" child of the matched elements. The css seems to be not applied to the 2nd menu. Is there any other css that could affect it? If possible, give us the link to the site that you are working on.

Comment: By the look, we can see that the "a" tag got an abnormal height, something is affecting it

Comment: published it, hacked a bit so that you dont have to log in. http://groupevents.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: and yeah, the li has a too large height which is inherited by the ahref. but still no clue why the css is not applied to the second menu. can't find any conflicting stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code is identical, but there are difference when displaying, it means that the css is affecting it. Without given us the css, it's impossible to tell what is the problem.

Here are css properties that could affect the total height of an element: height, line-height, padding, margin.

You can use Firebug or Chrome inspector to inspect an element to see its styles

**UPDATE**

bootmetro.css line 2018 is affecting (overriding) it

```
#top-info a {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 46px;   /**** should be removed or override *****/
   color: #5A5A5A;
}
```

Also I suggest you to use Firebug (an addon of firefox) to inspect elements, dont use the inspector of Firefox

Comment: hmm, ok. the CSS is the set of CSS in the bootmetro framework. I could post them but I can imagine that's a bit overkill (5 KLOC). I'll try to give it a shot. If anybody has the bootmetro on his/her PC and is willing to help me out: very much appreciated since I am no true-born hero in CSS.

Comment: Try to use elements inspector, it helps (firebug, chrome)

Comment: wtf! never used it, that is cool stuff. if I look at menu 1 (the correct one) then I can see that "a" takes the whole width of the menu. If I look at menu 2 (the "wrong" one) I can see that "li" takes the whole width, but "a" does not (it takes half, surrounding the text).

Comment: Yes and you can see all the css applied to it in the right column

Comment: question updated with more specifics, I hope you find the time to have a look at it. I'll continue looking but again, not quite an expert on this :)

Comment: I wish I could thank you more than just giving you virtual points. I would've NEVER figured this out without your help. Thanks a lot!!! Grtz, Bas